I booked a flight to Hawaii and had a valid ESTA but the airline staff said my ESTA been cancelled. How did that happen?
I had booked a flight to Hawaii. I had a valid ESTA but when I checked in the airport counter staff said my visa was not allowing me to check in as my ESTA visa was cancelled.
I was in Boston in September after my cruise for a few hrs and it was OK. How did that happen as my ESTA visa is valid for another 18 months?
I had to apply for another one and luckily it was granted but I had to pay for another flight the next day. Can I get compensation for this or who’s at fault?

What does the official ESTA site at https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/ say when you enter the details of your old ESTA?

Visa, ESTA etc. are always the passenger's responsibility. If you ESTA was indeed cancelled than this is your fault. If the airline was in in error, and your ESTA was valid at time of travel, you may have a claim for compensation (but that depends a lot on the details of your flight).

Did you replace your passport in the meanwhile?

I've had a case where I was re-routed at the last moment via the USA, didn't have an ESTA, and didn't even know I would need one (because I wasn't supposed to go there in the first place). Getting an ESTA took literally a few minutes. I'm surprised the check-in counter didn't let you try to get a new ESTA before cancelling your ticket

My passport all good . I did apply new Esta did not arrived on time gates all closed.

Contact CBP at esta@cbp.dhs.gov and ask if your previous ESTA was actually cancelled at any point. If they say it wasn't, save that email as proof and submit a claim to the airline for reimbursement of the new flight ticket.
If your flight was from the EU, UK or Turkey, you're also entitled to EUR 600/person in compensation.

As the OP stated they had to apply for a new ESTA, will this website show the status of the previous ESTA (as at the time it was replaced by the new one)?

@Midavalo Thanks, I swear I'm a bloody moron sometimes! They'll have to contact CBP and ask

I'd add on a couple hundred for the inconvenience as well, if you're not already entitled to it. If the airline messed up and cost you a day of your vacation, you should expect more than just to be made financially whole.

@Crazymoomin Nah, the amount is fixed and you're not legally entitled to demand more

@Crazydre That's only for E261. If you're not automatically entitled to additional compensation then it is worth demanding additional damages.

@Crazymoomin That's not routinely granted in court, so I wouldn't

@Crazydre You can absolutely demand damages for inconvenience and discomfort in a case like this. The CBP or airline would likely settle anyway before it got to court over something like this, especially the airline as they wouldn't want the bad publicity and a couple hundred or even thousand dollars is a small price to pay.

@Crazymoomin Airlines, especially major ones, don't give a toss about bad publicity, as they've been proving for many years. The fact is, getting what you're LEGALLY owed is hard as it is and often unjustly necessitates dragging them to court.

@Crazydre Airlines legally owe you whatever a court decides. If it's clearly their fault they know they will lose and they'll probably have to pay something on top of monetary damages and legal costs. It's cheaper for them to settle for monetary damages plus modest non monetary damages. You're clearly not going to get a million dollars for missing a day of vacation, but a few hundred or thousand or so isn't a lot in the grand scheme of things. It's a fraction of the legal fees they'd have to pay.
